# OpenAPI 3.0 - conditionally nested objects

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an API i'm trying to document using OpenAPI 3.0, which i'll then view using [Redoc](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc)

In this API, endpoints can include objects, and those objects can conditionally include other objects, and so on.

So for example: Object A can contain Object B, and Object B can contain Object C.  On endpoint 1, Object A contains Object B, and Object B contains Object C.  However, on endpoint 2.  Object B does NOT contain Object C

I'm trying to structure my components in the most DRY way possible, but where I also have complete flexibility as far as assembling the hierarchy of object schemas on a per-path basis.

Is it possible to accomplish this in a DRY manner using OpenAPI?

Comment: This is a great question btw, and I'd suggest also asking it in the [OpenAPI Specification repository](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues).

Comment: @Helen thank you!  I just posted the question there as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readOnly` and `writeOnly` keywords let you mark specific properties as included in responses only or in requests only, and [`discriminator`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#discriminator-object) lets you vary the whole schema based on the value of a specific property. But there's no way to vary nested schemas based on the path/operation where the schema is used.

The easiest solution is to define Object B's property that contains Object C as an optional property, and document the usage specifics verbally in the `description` (property description, schema description, or operation description).

Comment: thanks for your input! I figured i'd probably need to include some written direction, though it also made me wonder if this was an api-smell.

Comment: unfortunately I never received a reply on the OpenAPI github, but I did have a follow up question:  If I defined schema components for each individual object, can I piece the nesting together on a per endpoint basis?  ie. via `$refs`, say that the response contains objectA, which itself contains object B & C, and C contain D, etc